# babel with greek makes MikTeX run forever

Tags: packages

The command

```
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
```

makes MikTeX 2.9 run forever.

OS Windows 7

The output is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp3100/lyx_tmpbuf2/negreponti-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, inter
lingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayala
m, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, nynorsk, oriya, panjab
i, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, sl
ovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukengl
ish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, welsh, loaded.
```

**Edited:** from OP's comment, small code:

```
\makeatletter \makeatother 
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart} 
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter 
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} 

%\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic} 
%\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} %% LGR encoding is needed for gfsneohellenic 
\makeatother 
\begin{document} klkk \greektext γφγγ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add some more code? A minimal example that produces the problem.

Comment: Did you install the Greek language package? Use the MikTeX options to choose a language to install.

Comment: No error for me, but on TeX Live. Get rid of those `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: I did but nothing changes.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code (although it compiles OK here with TeX Live). You've made Greek the main document language but then try to switch to Greek which doesn't make much sense. Also, \greektext is supposed to take an argument according to the definition. Maybe that is causing issues. The version of babel you are using is quite old. Have you tried updating the package?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue cannot be reproduced